# Removing redundancies in a loop using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a huge input file that looks like this,

```
contig  protein start end
con1    P1  140 602
con1    P2  140 602
con1    P3  232 548
con2    P4  335 801
con2    P5  642 732
con2    P6  335 779
con2    P7  729 812
con3    P8  17  348
con3    P9  16  348
```

I would like to remove homologous P's or redundant P's, which I assume are those that have same start and end sites and the ones that have smaller start or end sites, respectively. So my output files will be like this,
file.txt

```
con1    P1  140 602
con1    P3  232 548
con2    P4  335 801
con2    P7  729 812
```

Attempted script, for some reason it doesn't meet both conditions,

```
from itertools import groupby
def non_homolog(hits):
    nonhomolog=[]
    overst = False
    for i in range(1,len(hits)):
        (p, c) = hits[i-1], hits[i]
        if p[2] <= c[2] and c[3] <= p[3]:
            if not overst: nonhomolog.append(c)
            nonhomolog.append(c)
            overst = True   
    return nonhomolog

fh = open('example.txt')
oh = open('nonhomologs.txt', 'w')
for qid, grp in groupby(fh, lambda l: l.split()[0]):
    hits = []
    for line in grp:
        hsp = line.split()
        hsp[2], hsp[3] = int(hsp[2]), int(hsp[3])
        hits.append(hsp)
    hits.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
    if non_homolog(hits):
        for hit in hits:
            oh.write('\t'.join([str(f) for f in hit])+'\n')
```

Comment: Possible problem: what if we have three items, say `con1 p1 140 602`, `con1 p2 144 602`. `con1 p3 148 602` => p1 is homologous to p2, p2 to p3, but not p1 to p3; how should this be treated?

Comment: I am primarily interested in once having difference of 0, basically identical start-end sites, then, just to compare the results consider also having +-5 units difference, may be less. So I suppose, your mentioned case go to homologs in the later case..

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell, to be honest, I am a bit cooked solving those problems, so for now may be better to concentrate on the ones that are identical, I have to think about that case, cos some of my con's have <10-20 hits..

Comment: By +-5, can you just round down to the next lowest 5 (801 and 803 to 800, 807 and 808 to 805)? Then you can treat them as identical for comparison and even use tuples like (140,600) as keys in a dict for easy lookup.

Comment: @user3224522: so to rephrase: homologs contains all rows which are homologous to anything else (not just pairs of homologous values)?

Comment: @tdelaney: bad programmer, no donut - consider `con1 p1 139 602` and `con1 p2 141 602`.

Comment: @HughBothwell, depends on how you want to estimate the data set. Consider `con1 p1 139 602`, `con1 p1 142 602` and `con1 p1 145 602`. These would group differently depending on how you scanned the list. I'm suggesting that you put the data in buckets first... not so uncommon, especially if the data has +=2.5 accuracy.

Comment: OK,guys, thanks for your useful comments,I changed and updated my question. I want to delete homologous and redundant P's for now. Sorry, for any confusion

Comment: I am not very much positive about rounding..but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
# this code assumes Python 2.7
from itertools import groupby, izip
from operator import attrgetter

INPUT    = "file.txt"
HOMO_YES = "homologs.txt"
HOMO_NO  = "nonhomologs.txt"
MAX_DIFF = 5

class Row:
    __slots__ = ["line", "con", "protein", "start", "end"]

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.line    = s.rstrip()
        data         = s.split()
        self.con     = data[0]
        self.protein = data[1]
        self.start   = int(data[2])
        self.end     = int(data[3])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.line

def count_homologs(items, max_diff=MAX_DIFF):
    num_items  = len(items)
    counts     = [0] * num_items
    # first item
    for i, item_i in enumerate(items):
        max_start = item_i.start + max_diff
        max_end   = item_i.end   + max_diff
        # second item
        for j in xrange(i+1, num_items):
            item_j = items[j]
            if item_j.start > max_start:
                break
            elif item_j.end <= max_end:
                counts[i] += 1
                counts[j] += 1
    return counts

def main():
    with open(INPUT) as inf, open(HOMO_YES, "w") as outhomo, open(HOMO_NO, "w") as outnothomo:
        # skip header
        next(inf, '')
        rows = (Row(line) for line in inf)

        for con, item_iter in groupby(rows, key=attrgetter("con")):
            # per-con list of Rows sorted by start,end
            items = sorted(item_iter, key=attrgetter("start", "end"))
            # get #homologs for each item
            counts = count_homologs(items)
            # do output
            for c,item in izip(counts, items):
                if c:
                    outhomo.write(str(item) + "\n")
                else:
                    outnothomo.write(str(item) + "\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

on your given data, produces:

=== homologs.txt ===

```
con1    P1  140 602
con1    P2  140 602
con3    P9  16  348
con3    P8  17  348
```

=== nonhomologs.txt ===

```
con1    P3  232 548
con2    P6  335 779
con2    P4  335 801
con2    P5  642 732
con2    P7  729 812
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!I tried to run it and it gives me an invalid syntax error when opening block using with..

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Well, there's your problem :-)  2.6 supports `with` but not chaining: instead of `with a, b, c:` you have to do `with a: with b: with c:`.